# Linkbutton in Master page is not being fired When I click on it

Tags: asp.net, onclick, master-pages, linkbutton

I have a linkbutton in master page is as follows:

```
<ul class="links">
    <li class="first"><a href="NewsArchive.aspx" title="News">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="MyWishList.aspx" title="My Wishlist">My Wishlist</a></li>
    <li><a href="MainUserPage.aspx" title="My Account">My Account</a></li>
    <li class="last"><asp:LinkButton ID="LoginBTN" runat="server" onclick="LoginBTN_Click" Text="Login"></asp:LinkButton></li>
</ul>
```

And LoginBTN_Click is as follows:

```
protected void LoginBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (LoginBTN.Text == "Login")
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
    else
    {
        Session["IsAuthenticated"] = "False";
        Session["UserID"] = ""; Session["Name"] = ""; Session["Lname"] = ""; Session["Email"] = "";
        Session["Address"] = ""; Session["NewsLetter"] = ""; Session["UserStatus"] = ""; Session["LockUser"] = "";
        Session["LastLoginDate"] = ""; Session["Search"] = ""; Session["ShopingID"] = ""; Session["ChangePage"] = "";
        Session["Command"] = ""; Session["ContactID"] = ""; Session["SelectedIndex"] = ""; Session["LockUser"] = "";
        Session["UploadFileName"] = ""; Session["AgancyID"] = ""; Session["ReqCode"] = ""; Session["EditFlag"] = "";
        RegisterLBTN.CssClass = "";
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
}
```

and in Page_Load of master page is as follows:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
   if (Session["IsAuthenticated"].ToString() == "True")
   {
      LoginBTN.Text = "Exit";
   }
}
```

when i run web site locally, Everything runs fine but when i run website on net, my linkbutton click event is not fired. But it is surprising to say When I'm on the registration page(register.aspx, NewsArchive.aspx, ... does not matter) and click on linkbutton, my code is work and redirect to login.aspx page.

I do not know exactly where the problem is?

Comment: check the console may be you have a JS error

Comment: if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
   if (Session["IsAuthenticated"].ToString() == "True")
   {
      LoginBTN.Text = "Exit";
   } else LoginBTN.Text = "Login";
}

Comment: @Mazdak Shojaie. when i type url in address bar (for example:www.test.com) and My website was fully loaded, when i click on login button, my click event is not fired and i can't redirect to login.aspx And Home page for me to reload. but when i'm on for example NewsArchive.aspx and click on login button, my click event is fired and i can redirect to login.aspx. Is there another solution to this problem?

Comment: Set a break point on LoginBTN_Click event. Your project is a website or an application? Did you built project before uploading?

Comment: Also, I suggest to check Session["IsAuthenticated"] value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple solution:

LoginLBTN.PostBackUrl = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

add this code in your Page_Load().

best regards